# Can I use Snowsight filters as a parameter to Snowflake Stored Procedure call?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to do anything with Snowsight filters other than literally

```
:= :MyFilter
```

I find this EXTREMELY limited...

For instance, many developers will want to use stored procedures and user defined functions rather than adhoc SQL...
In which case, one would want to do this instead

```
call MyDb.MySchema.MyProc(:MyFilter);
```

I have found I can use this in a worksheet

```
SET MyVar = :Filter
call MyDb.MySchema.MyProc($MyVar);
```

and then I would have to turn this into a SQL Scripting block if using in a Dashboard... but I don't manage to get it working

```
DECLARE 
    MyVar STRING;
BEGIN
    SET MyVar = :MyFilter;
    
    CALL MyDb.MySchema.MyProc(:MyVar);
END;
```

I get an error
*Error: invalid identifier 'MyFilter'*

Am I missing a trick?

My goal is to drive Dashboards from Stored procedures rather than adhoc code, hence I can use Source Control...

Answer (score 0):

If you using Classic Console then use following code

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
DECLARE 
    MyVar INTEGER;
    RetResultSet resultset;
BEGIN
     MyVar := 10;
    
     RetResultSet:= (CALL MyDb.MySchema.MyProc(:MyVar));
     return  table(RetResultSet);
END;
$$;
```

If you using SnowSight

```
 DECLARE 
        MyVar INTEGER;
        RetResultSet resultset;
    BEGIN
         MyVar := 10;
        
         RetResultSet:= (CALL MyDb.MySchema.MyProc(:MyVar));
         return  table(RetResultSet);
    END;
```

Comment: I believe the ask was for how to use Snowsight filters, not generally declared variables.

Comment: That's correct.
I have no problem when using a hard-coded value but I can't get it to work with a filter

Comment: I tried to work around that problem by assigning the filter value to a variable but this is where I get the error message.